# What is the correct name of this quantum gate? Possibly state control gate

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, pauli-gates, universal-gates, terminology-and-notation

Let $\vec v \in \mathbb{C}^2 $ be the following quantum state:
$$
\vec v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
           v_{1} \\
           v_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix},\space \lvert v_1 \rvert = 1, \space \lvert v_2 \rvert = 1
$$

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the following quantum gate:

$$
\mathbb{A} = cos (\phi)\cdot\sigma_1+sin(\phi)\cdot\sigma_2,
$$
where, $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ are Pauli matrices and the angle $\phi$ is the solution to the equation:
$$
\frac{v_2}{v_1} = e^{i\phi}
$$

With these definitions the matrix $\mathbb{A}$ has the property:
$$\mathbb{A}\vec v = \vec v $$

I am a mathematical physicist not well versed in quantum computing terminology, does this gate have a specific name in the field? I would call it a state control gate. I would believe it must be an important notion in the field, I would welcome any further explanation of the importance of this gate in the field of quantum computing.

Note:
$\mathbb{A}$ and $\vec{v}$ can be generalized to $n$-dimensions. The general form of the matrix is the following:
$$
\mathbb{A} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{v_2}{v_1} & \cdots & \frac{v_n}{v_1}\\
    \frac{v_1}{v_2} & 0 & \cdots & \frac{v_n}{v_2}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \frac{v_1}{v_n} & \frac{v_2}{v_n} & \cdots & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix},
$$
where,
$$
\mathbb{A}\vec{v} = (n-1)\vec{v}
$$

In dimension 3 the matrix is a combination of the Gell-mann matrices.